# Allowing a change of value of pre-set text in Tkinter Entry fields via the GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the code below to create a hand-full of input fields, However although all fields are correctly created, I am then unable to chance the values upon selecting them in the GUI. I can hi-light the text already made, however never input anything. Does anyone have any ideas why this may be happening.

```
 #importystuffs#


def makeform(check, fields,values):
  entries = []
  for field in fields:
  row = tk.Frame(check)
  lab = tk.Label(row, width=15, text=field, anchor='w')
  ent = tk.Entry(row)

  #ent.insert(tk.END, values[field])

  ent.configure(state=tk.NORMAL)
  row.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X, padx=5, pady=5)
  lab.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
  ent.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.X)
  entries.append((field, ent))

  return entries


#program
f= open ('input.details', 'r')
e = [ line.replace('\n','') for line in f.readlines()] 

names=[ 'Name', 'Address_line1','Address_line2','Email','Standard','LC','other']
values= dict(zip(names,e))

check = tk.Tk()
check.overrideredirect(True)


#bg image
im = Image.open('img2.png')
tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
myvar=tk.Label(check,image = tkimage)
myvar.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

ents = makeform(check, names,values)
```

Alternatively writing the code this way also gives me the same problem

```
button={}
   for element in names:
       infoz = tk.Label(frame, text=element ,bg='white')
       infoz.pack()
       button[element] = tk.Entry(frame)
       button[element].pack()
       button[element].insert(10, values[element])

 #print z.get()   

print button['Name'].get()

z = tk.Entry(frame)
z.pack()


check.focus_force()
check.after(10000, run_program)   # kills program     
check.mainloop()
```

Comment: BTW: you forgot `mainloop()`. If you run it in IDLE then it works event without `mainloop()` but if you will run it outside IDLE then it will not work without `mainloop()`.

Comment: BTW: `return entries` needs indention.

Comment: Could you provide a copiable/pastable/runnable example that doesn't require `input.details` or `img2.png`?

Comment: @furas mainloop and return entries are correct in normal code, those were just a mistake in copying it to stackoverflow.

Comment: Then always use button `{}` on pasted code.

Comment: @Kevin  http://pastebin.com/UXFB51dy (apologies for the messy code, but this should run)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for me your problem is `check.overrideredirect(True)`.

You use it to make window without border (or to make fullscreen program) but in some systems it meens also no keyboard access to that window.